# Display Highest Offer, But Still Display With No Offer

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display businesses along with their highest discount offer. But I still would like to display businesses with no offer.

Businesses are stored in `business_tb`

```
business_id | business_name
------------+---------------
     1      |      aaa
     2      |      bbb
     3      |      ccc
```

offered discounts by those businesses are stored in `deal_offer_tb`

```
deal_offer_id | business_id | deal_id 
--------------+-------------+----------
       1      |      1      |    3
       2      |      1      |    2
       3      |      2      |    0
       4      |      1      |    1
       5      |      3      |    3
```

and types of discounts are stored in `deal_tb`.

```
deal_id | discount
--------+----------
    1   |    40%
    2   |    30%
    3   |    20%
    4   |    10%
```

So the display I wanted should look something like this:

```
 1 |  aaa | 40%
 2 |  bbb | ---
 3 |  ccc | 20%
```

But with my current query:

```
SELECT a.business_id, a.business_name, c.discount
    FROM business_tb a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT min(deal_id) AS deal_id, business_id FROM deal_offer_tb GROUP BY business_id) b ON a.business_id = b.business_id
    LEFT JOIN deal_tb c ON b.deal_id = c.deal_id
```

I only get:

```
 1 | aaa | 40%
 3 | ccc | 20%
```

It does not display businesses with no offered discounts.

How am I suppose to get my desired output?

---

**UPDATE:** I don't know what happened earlier, but my query is working the way I wanted it. Thanks to the effort of those who answered. Appreciate it, big time!

Comment: Your query should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yes, but it doesn't display businesses without offered discounts.

Comment: I can’t see where the `30%` for `ccc` comes from. According to `deal_offer_tb`, business 3 is associated with deal 3, which gives 20%.

Comment: I think you should be using a subquery to find the maximum discounts for each business.  I don't see you doing this anywhere currently.

Comment: @Manngo - `ccc` should be `20%`. Updated post

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by using a subquery to find the greatest discount for each business, joining the `deal_offer_tb` and `deal_tb` tables.  Then, join this subquery to the `business_tb` table to get the final result.  Note that I use an initial `LEFT JOIN` to account for that a given business may not even have an deals associated with it.  In that case, I assign a maximum discount of 0 to that business (which makes sense, since then the full regular price would apply).

```
SELECT
    t1.business_id,
    t1.business_name,
    COALESECE(t2.max_discount, 0) AS max_discount
FROM business_tb t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.business_id, MAX(t2.discount) AS max_discount
    FROM deal_offer_tb t1
    INNER JOIN deal_tb t2
        ON t1.deal_id = t2.deal_id
    GROUP BY t1.business_id
) t2
    ON t1.business_id = t2.business_id
```

Comment: Edit: Yep. Still not working. `bbb` is still not there.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev Please try again.  I didn't realize you had businesses with no matching deals.  Using an initial `LEFT JOIN` should resolve this problem.

Comment: *COALESCE. Updated answer looks promising

Answer (score 1):

This query is essentially your query (with table aliases):

```
SELECT b.business_id, b.business_name, d.discount
FROM business_tb b LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(deal_id) AS deal_id, business_id
      FROM deal_offer_tb dot
      GROUP BY business_id
     ) dot
     ON b.business_id = dot.business_id LEFT JOIN
     deal_tb d
     ON d.deal_id = dot.deal_id;
```

By the definition of `LEFT JOIN`, it will keep all rows in `business_tb`, regardless of whether or not there are matches in the rest of the `FROM` clause.  You have no additional filtering (via `WHERE`) or aggregation.  Hence, this should returns all the rows in `business_tb`.

Comment: `discount` column is in `deal_tb`, and not in `deal_offer_tb` (alias as `dot`). But I don't see any difference with my current query except for the aliases you uses.

Comment: @GrandMarshalBraev . . . (Thank you for the catch on `discount`.)  This is essentially your query.  By the definition of `LEFT JOIN`, it should be returning all the rows in `business_tb`.

Comment: Thank you very much! But upon checking of my current query, it is now working the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to do the query:

```
SELECT
    a.business_id, a.business_name, b.max
FROM business_tb a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        c.business_id, MAX(d.discount) AS max
    FROM deal_offer_tb c
    LEFT JOIN deal_tb d ON c.deal_id = d.deal_id
    GROUP BY c.business_id
) b ON a.business_id = b.business_id;
```

You don't have `deal_id` 0 in `deal_tb`, so I assume it's `null` for `deal_offer_id` 3.